# vue cli 3 – use background image in style tag

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-cli

I want to use a svg image from my assets folder in one of my components as a background-image. Here is an example of my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="container"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'component'
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.container {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-image: url('@/assets/image.svg');
}
</style>
```

But the image doesn't show. The Path is correct. Where is my mistake?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've tried every possible path that comes to my mind.

Comment: Could you please try `url('~@/assets/image.svg')`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Can you explain why to use @ and ~? The documentation explains both of them as a module request

Comment: As one of possible explanations I've found (with the use Google) [that](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/193#issuecomment-206510064):
`vue-html-loader` and `css-loader` translates non-root URLs to relative paths. In order to treat it like a module path, prefix it with `~`

Comment: However, the output is an object not the image svg.  How to get the image svg code instead of an object?

Comment: @MaxMartynov can you post this comment as an answer please? It works.

Comment: I used vue cli 3 and tried `url('~@/assets/image.svg')` but that didn't work, I don't know why.

Comment: @SkuraZZ could you resolve it yet?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu I solved it in this way:  in template,  `:style="{backgroundImage: 'url('+bgImages[0]+')'}"`, in data, `bgImages: [require("@/assets/images/login/1.png")],`. It's not the best practice, but at least it works.

Comment: @SkuraZZ i'm surprised there is no definitive answer or direction on this from vue-team... it has come up so many times

Comment: I've tried all these options apart from style binding. Nothing works.

Comment: This worked for me. `:style="{ 'background-image' : 'url(' + require('../../../blah/blah_blah/file_name.blah') + ')'}"`

Comment: `background-image: url(~@/assets/images/logo.png);` (no quotes around the image path) worked for me.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

As **Max Martynov**, highlighted in the comments, you should use `url('~@/assets/image.svg')`.

Webpack has some specific rules when resolving assets<sup>[[1]](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html#asset-resolving-rules)</sup>.

In order to resolve an alias (`@`), as you are using, it is mandatory webpack handles the request as a module request. Using the prefix `~` enforces webpack to treat the request as a module request, similar to `require('some-module/image.svg')`.

### References

1. https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html#asset-resolving-rules

Comment: Took me 2 days to get to some straight explanation. For non native english people like me, the docs gets really really freaking difficult. I think vue team took a step away not describing it in an of their free resources. such a simple thing got so much confusing, there is an issue on vue repo with hundreds of comments and reactions about this. Wish I could opvote you a million times.

Comment: @Bsienn, I can't express how much I appreciate your comment! But, I think the praise should be directed to Max and Stackoverflow. I encourage everyone to upvote his comment :)

Comment: Ragaar and Max Thanks, sure provided a solution. both his and your description finally made it work and explained to me why it is the way it is 'Modules/webpack`.  This should be first thing in the docs with example somewhere. Many thanks

Answer (score 42):

I would recommend using style binding. I found this thread really helpful [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/646#issuecomment-377683536).

Here an example using bootstrap cards

```
    <div
      class="card-image"
      :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require('@/assets/images/cards.jpg') + ')' }">
```

The image is in src/assets/images/cards.jpg

Comment: This solved the issue for me - went through allot of iterations - but looks like any image being used in an assets folder must be required() to be loaded properly (this is my observation from trial and error - so please don't take it as gospel)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the image extension is lowercase. If the image has an uppercase extension, change it to be lowercase otherwise it won't work.

```
<style lang="scss">
  .section{
    background-image: url('~@/assets/photos/DSC08611.jpg'); //WORKED!
    background-image: url('~@/assets/photos/DSC08611.JPG'); //DID NOT WORK
  }

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

```
<div
  class="image"
  v-for="(image, imageIndex) in slideshow"
  :key="imageIndex"
  :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(`@/assets/${image}`) + ')', width: '300px', height: '200px' }"
></div>
```

Where `slideshow` looks like:

```
data() {
      return {
        slideshow : [
          "MyImages/1.png",
          "MyImages/2.png"
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was the following:

1. Move the desired image to the public folder (myapp/public/assets/myimage.png)
2. Build the project. This will move the assets from the public folder to the dist folder.

`npm run build`

3. Now you can use your image in the component like this:

```
<div :style="{background: 'url(' + '\'/assets/myimage.png\'' + ') no-repeat 0 3px'}"  ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your vuejs uses `file-loader`, you'll take advantage of `import`.

```
<template>
  <div class="container"></div>
</template>

import image from @/assets/image.svg
<script>
export default {
  name: 'component'
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.container {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-image: url(image);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vue 3 (TypeScript) and Vite 3.2+, in your `vite.config.ts`, set your base appropriately as shown below.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/subfolder/' : '/',
});
```

*The base option is used for specifying the base URL of your application, and it automatically handles the resolution of asset paths.*

Then if your image, img.jpg, is in `public/images` folder, you can reference it in your css as:

```
background-image: url('/images/img.jpg');
```

Upon building for production, this will be resolved to:

```
background-image: url('/subfolder/images/img.jpg');
```