# How to fix module not found error in vue cli?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli-3

I am getting following error when I am trying to run my vue cli application. I have put my style.css file in assests folder and images in public/images folder.Then I have imported css file into main.js folder like this:"import "./assets/style.css";" Can anyone help me out. I have paste the error below.
My app was working before but Its not working now.

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./images/beeton-small-logo.png in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-3-2!./src/assets/style.css
```

Comment: You didn't show your CSS for using the image but that's where the problem is

Comment: @Dan This is my css using image: background: rgba(131, 133, 136, 0.3) url(images/beeton-small-logo.png) repeat;

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030632/2185093).  It's probably best to move the images folder into assets and use `url('~@/assets/images/beeton-small-logo.png')`

Comment: @Dan Thanks for ur reponse. I tried but it did not work..

Comment: What's the new error?  Verify that there is an `images` folder inside your `assets` folder (not your `public` folder).  If so, you'll need to provide more info because it should work.

Comment: I have put  images like this assets/images/beeton-small-logo.png and css assets/styles/style.css. How it will work?

Comment: You didn't answer:  what is the new error.  Show your new CSS code and tell what the new error says.